# Checking convergence/ divergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{\log{x}}{x^2}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I tried 2 tests, but both failed.

Test-1:

checking the integrand, $\log{x}\le x$ in the domain, $\frac{\log{x}}{x^2} \le \frac{x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ is divergent by p-series test, but we cant say anything about the smaller integral.

Test-2:

Splitting the given integral as $\int_1^\infty$=$\int_1^3$+$\int_3^\infty$. The first term is a proper integral and hence finite, the second can be solved by considering fact that $\log{x}>1, \forall x \ge 3$, and hence, $\frac{\log{x}}{x^2} \ge \frac{1}{x^2}$ ($x\ge 3$) and we have $\int_3^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ convergent by p-series test, but we cant say anything about the larger integral.

So please help on how to approach this problem.

Comment: How would you say that $\log x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ compare as $x \to +\infty$?

Comment: both go to $+\infty$ ??but i dont get your hint...

Comment: You had the idea to use $\log x \leq x$. Could you prove that $\log x \leq \sqrt{x}$ and use it?

Comment: I can certainly use it by p-series test where $p=3/2$ , but i dont know how to prove it...

Comment: How do you know / did you prove that $\log(x)\leq x$? You can try to adapt the proof.

Comment: My teacher told me in lecture, and also its well known. I also saw the graph of x being always above log x, but i did not try to prove myself

Comment: It is fairly "well-known" and visible on the graph that $\log(x) \leq \sqrt{x}$. You can prove it as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572398/prove-that-log-x-sqrtx-for-x-geq-1).

Comment: @cs89 thanks, now I have a follow up question: what is the minimum $a>0$ such that $x^a \ge \log{x}$

Comment: For every $a > 0$, there exists $x^* > 0$ (depending on $a$) such that $x^a \geq \log x$ for $x \geq x^*$. But this is of course false with $a = 0$, since $\log x$ is not bounded by $1$.

Comment: [Computing whether $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{x^2}dx$
 converges or diverges using the comparison theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3304371/721644)

Comment: @cs89 I had meant to ask the question for all values of $x>0$ such that $x^a \ge \log{x}$, what will be minimum a>0... I tried ot plot graphs and saw that $x^{1/e}$ is above ln(x) but $x^{1/3}$ goes below lnx..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know that $\log x \leqslant x$, use $\log x = 2 \log x^{1/2}\leqslant 2 x^{1/2}$ to get the estimate

$$\frac{\log x}{x^2}\leqslant \frac{2x^{1/2}}{x^2}= \frac{2}{x^{3/2}}$$

The presence of a constant is irrelevant in applying the comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

By parts, you get the integral
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log{x}}{x^{2}} \ dx = -\frac{\log{x}}{x} \mid_{1}^{\infty} + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}} \ dx = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}} \ dx$$
And then the convergence is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide an answer building upon your "Test-1" and discussions we had in the comments.

Similarly as $\log x \leq x$, there also holds $\log x \leq \sqrt{x}$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572398/prove-that-log-x-sqrtx-for-x-geq-1) for a proof). Hence, the integrand is bounded above by $x^{-\frac 32}$, for which you can apply successfully your convergence test.